# Subsonic 2.2 doesn't support .NET Framework 4.0 Windows Application?

Tags: winforms, integration, subsonic2.2, dll-reference

I am using .net framework 4.0 and after adding reference of subsonic 2.2 dll.  Once I compiled the reference disappeared, I google it, I came to know it uses system.web.dll.

I have compiled subsonic2.2 source code with framework4.0 and try to add the reference but still the same.

Here is the error I am getting:

> 'SubSonic' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Answer (score 0):

Check your project settings to make sure you're not targeting the ".NET 4.0 Client Profile", but the full framework.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx